# Como alterar as cores dos geom_points no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
```

Suponha o seguinte df:

```
Ano<-c(2012:2020)
Janeiro<-c(112,127,121,131,150,158,137,165,164)
Fevereiro<-c(101,101,94,114,126,119,122,138,144)
Março<-c(97,101,101,123,126,138,137,154,114)
Abril<-c(97,94,97,122,125,141,129,142,6)
Maio<-c(96,98,98,136,126,135,136,144,4)

fen<-data.frame(Ano, Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março, Abril, Maio)
```

Depois:
Uso "gather" para colocar os dados no formato tidy;
Uso "mutate" junto com "ymd" e "paste" para colocar os anos no formato "Date";
Uso "select" para selecionar as colunas que me interessam;
Uso "arrange" para organizar em ordem cronológica;
Uso o "ggplot"+ "geom-line" e "geom_point" para criar o gráfico.

```
fen %>% 
  gather(mes, n_voos, c(Janeiro:Maio)) %>% 
  mutate(dt=ymd(paste(Ano, mes, "1"))) %>% 
  select(dt, n_voos) %>% 
  arrange(dt) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(dt, n_voos))+
  geom_point(aes(dt, n_voos))
```

O resultado é:

[image: Grafico_1]

Minha dúvida:
Há alguma forma de eu COLORIR os pontos de acordo com os meses?
Por exemplo: gostaria de todos os meses de Janeiro com a cor azul, todos os de Fevereiro com a cor verde, todos os de Março de preto, e assim por diante.

Tentei adicionar um "col=dt" na última linha, mas o resultado gerou uma alteração nas cores dos pontos segundo os ANOS. Ficou assim:

```
fen %>% 
  gather(mes, n_voos, c(Janeiro:Maio)) %>% 
  mutate(dt=ymd(paste(Ano, mes, "1"))) %>% 
  select(dt, n_voos) %>% 
  arrange(dt) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(dt, n_voos))+
  geom_point(aes(dt, n_voos, col=dt))
```

Ficou assim:

[image: Grafico_2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para colorir segundo os meses, deve usar `mes` em `aes(color = mes)`, não a data `dt`, como está no código da pergunta.
Note ainda que apesar do `gather` funcionar e ser a forma usada no passado, o pacote `tidyr` tem agora `help('pivot_longer')`, a forma recomendada.

```
fen %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = Janeiro:Maio,
    names_to = "mes",
    values_to = "n_voos"
  ) %>%
  mutate(dt = ymd(paste(Ano, mes, "1")),
         mes = factor(mes, levels = c("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(dt, n_voos)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color = mes))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela dica sobre o "pivot_longer". A propósito: e como relação ao "spread" (costumo usar como o oposto do "gather") há alguma dica? Ou sigo com o "spread"?

Comment: @itamar Agora há o `pivot_wider`. Mas tanto o `gather` como o `spread` não vão desaparecer. Isto é dito nas páginas de help do [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)  e do [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html). Em ambos os casos na última frase da secção Details. Portanto, se está habituado a usar as funções mais antigas, e para as quais há muitos exemplos na rede e no SO, não haverá problema. Eu acho que as novas funções são mais intuitivas e mais flexíveis.